# Spring: Receiving form-data from a dynamic jquery-form

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

Hy,

I'm using jQuery in Spring MVC for a dynamic generation of form-elements.

Here's an example: [*click*](http://jsbin.com/onahi4/2)

How can I receive the data from the dynamic form-fields?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the values a List or Collection of some sort in your form bean.  In your JSP you can create an input like:

```
<input type="text" name="formBean.listName[0]" />
```

Or whatever input type you want.  In your controller, you would have the form bean as your model attribute, something like:
@RequestMapping("/someUrl")

```
public String myHandler(@ModelAttribute("formBean") FormBean formBean) {
    // ...do something
}
```

Basically, as long as the name attribute of the input matches the ModelAttribute name and its internal list name, you should be golden.  You can also use a Map instead, substituting the index in the list of the key to the Map.

Comment: Thank you very much,CodeChimp! - This seems to work! And could you finally give me an example for "//...do something"? I would like to see if I get the right data...

Comment: The "// ...do something" is whatever you want the controller to do when it handles that particular type of request.  For instance, you may want to write the values to a DB, or send an email, or take then input and use it for some other process.  Whatever your app needs to do when it gets that request.  As far as validation, I would suggest two things: 1) Take a look at Spring's InitBinder and the BindingResult object, and 2) Take a look at Spring's JSR 303 validation implementation.